# vba excel: how to copy worksheet with images but without buttons

Tags: vba, excel

i have a worksheet with an image and 2 buttons. (invoice)
i would like to copy the worksheet with the image but without the 2 buttons into a new sheet of a new workbook and i wanna do it with a vba macro. 
in the moment i do it with the usual copy command and use an extra delete command for the 2 buttons.

i am sure there is a easier way to do it. 
i tried this...

```
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False
Sheets("invoice").Select
Sheets("invoice").Move After:=Workbooks("invoices").Sheets(1)
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
```

these looses the buttons but the image is also gone. but i would like to keep the image.

i hope you guys can help me with this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The explanations are in the comments in the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheet_WO_Btn()

Dim newWB                       As Workbook
Dim ShtOrig                     As Worksheet

Dim Obj                         As OLEObject
Dim PicShape                    As Shape
Dim PicLeft                     As Double
Dim PicTop                      As Double

Set ShtOrig = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("invoice")

' loop through all objects in "invoice" sheet
For Each Obj In ShtOrig.OLEObjects

    ' if OLE Object is type CommanButton make it Un-Visible (not to copy with the sheet)
    If Obj.progID = "Forms.CommandButton.1" Then
        Obj.Visible = False
    End If

Next Obj

Set newWB = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
ShtOrig.Copy newWB.Sheets(1)

' loop through all shapes in "invoice" sheet and copy the pictures
For Each PicShape In ShtOrig.Shapes
    If PicShape.Name = "Picture 1" Then
        PicLeft = PicShape.Left
        PicTop = PicShape.Top
        PicShape.Copy

        newWB.Sheets(1).Paste
        Selection.ShapeRange.Left = PicLeft
        Selection.ShapeRange.Top = PicTop
    End If
Next PicShape

' loop again and return the CommandButtons to be Visible in "invoice" sheet
For Each Obj In ShtOrig.OLEObjects
    Obj.Visible = True
Next Obj

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! this is a bit too massive for my little invoice but you gave me a great idea. i found out with your help how to make the buttons invisible, then copy the worksheet into the new workbook and then make the buttons in the original invoice visible again! thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by too massive ?